# Do objects with position: absolute reference the html elements height or the viewport?

Tags: html, css, dom

I created codepens which demonstrate confusing behavior in regards to the positioning of elements

The [First Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNeMRj?editors=1100) shows a block element with position:absolute and bottom:10px

```
 <div class="block_element square absolute">
 Example
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 <!-- a bunch of lorem ipsum -->
 </div>
```

This absolute positioning shows correct behavior and positions 10px up from the bottom of the screen

The [Second Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpMXBr) has javascript which grabs the height of the html element and displays it inside a div which is 5000px in height

```
var o = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(o);
var p = styles.getPropertyValue('height');
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = p;
```

The height of the html element is showing as a height greater than screen height which goes against the common belief that html height and width are equal to screen size. Such as seen [Here](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)

"The html element's height and width are controlled by the browser window"
(from above link)

Why is the html element height not equal to screen height? and if this is so, what is position: absolute referencing?

Comment: For the second issue, you'll want to have a look at the css box model. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model Setting `box-sizing:border-box;` would give you the expected 5000px

Comment: The issue is not that the height is greater than 5000px, it is that <html> height is greater than screen height at all. What is position absolute referencing if not the height of <html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Absolutely positioned](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) elements are offset with respect to their containing block.

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block.

For them, the [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) is

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is
>   established by the nearest ancestor with a [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) of `absolute`,
>   `relative` or `fixed`, in the following way:
>
> 1. In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and
>      the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the
>      inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is
>      undefined.
> 2. Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the [padding edge](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-edge) of the ancestor.
>
> If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the initial
>   containing block.

In your case there is no positioned ancestor, so the containing block is [the initial one](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#x1):

> The containing block in which the [root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#root) lives is a rectangle
>   called the *initial containing block*. For continuous media, it has the
>   dimensions of the [viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport) and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is
>   the [page area](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-area) for paged media.

And no, by default the height of the root element is given by its contents, it's not the height of the viewport. But you can achieve that with

```css
html { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: So is the _initial containing block_ not part of the markup? What default properties does the _initial containing block_  have? is this the same as document.window in javascript?

Comment: Containing blocks are not HTML elements nor JS objects, they are just rectangles (which can be established by HTML elements). In this case, the initial one is established by the viewport (the part of the browser window where the page is rendered).

Comment: It is still unclear to me where in the hierarchy this _initial containing block_ falls. Is it generated by the browser renderer? is it part of the DOM? What are the steps in the hierarchy between the containing block generated by the <html> element and this _initial containing block_?

Comment: @Ace.C There is no hierarchy nor tree nor anything. Containing blocks are not part of the DOM. They are not objects. They are just rectangles. The initial one has the same sizes as the viewport. The containing block of the `<html>` element is the initial one. Assuming the `<html>` element is a block, it will establish a containing block for its non-absolutely positioned descendants, which will have the same sizes as the `<html>` element.

Comment: So are you saying there are two containing block associated with <html>? one which is viewport size, and the other which is content sized?

Comment: @Ace.C The containing block of `<html>` is established by the viewport. `<html>` can establish a containing block for some of its descendants. It's the opposite relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In the second pen, the height `5028px` represents the sum of `5000px` + `10px` (padding) + `2px` (borders) + the *default* `padding` of the `body`.

Try adding the following line:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

and comment the `padding` and `border` and remove the default margin of the `body`, will show you `5000px` as in [this fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/aNKoNN).

Comment: This question is not about padding and margins

Answer (score 0):

5000px (`.box` height) + 8px (`body` top margin) + 8px (`body` bottom margin) + 5px (`.box` top padding) + 5px (`.box` bottom padding) + 1px (`.box` top border) + 1px (`.box` bottom border) = 5028px.

Comment: This question is not about padding and margins